# Configure self sizing cell inside willDisplay

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I `UITableViewDataSrouce` looks like :

I dequeue cell inside `cellForRowAt` :

...

```
case is ComponentType:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checkboxCell") as! ComponentTypeCell
```

...

Configure data cell inside `willDisplay` :

...

```
case is ComponentType:
            guard let cell = cell as? ComponentTypeCell else { return }
            cell.configure(with: model, at: indexPath)
```

...

Where is the problem ? My `UITableView` have self-sizing cells and the difference between `cellForRowAt` and `willDisplay` is that : If inside my `configure(...)` method I have :

```
titleLabel.text = "Something"
```

And the call is going to be inside `willDisplay` like from the above it is not going to display any text and the cell is going to have default size. Whenver I swap the call to `cellForRowAt` it is going to work. Any ideas why is that happening ? It's a bit werid behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what it seems to be the problem but try,
first to replace this method with the safe one:

```
case is ComponentType:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checkboxCell") as! ComponentTypeCell

tableView.dequeueReusableCell(type: "checkboxCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Also include this if u haven't:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```